# Trying to Redirect User to a Home page (Index.html) when they are signed out

Tags: python, django, httpresponse, valueerror

I have been trying to solve one problem regarding redirect to another html page.
I am creating a simple Restaurant Booking System (using python Django etc.) that will show the user (once logged in) their bookings to date, to amend or delete bookings and create a new booking. For the Admin, they can view and approve or reject bookings. But once logged out the user will see the main page describing the restaurant etc.

The issue I am facing is that every time I log out as both admin and user, I am getting an Anonymous error message which I know the system needs someone to be signed in for a page to appear.

So I created a new index.html and created the following:

Index.html:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmIIu.png)

base.html:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkrji.png)

the apps (booking) model.py:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOTrZ.png)

the apps (booking) view.py:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHXfv.png)

the apps (booking) urls.py:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUIDY.png)

After all that I managed to get this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l69pe.png)

Where am I going wrong? I have tried everything.

**I tried everything as per the below in the views.py file:**
`from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views import generic, View
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from .models import Booking
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def index(request):
if not request.user.is_authenticated:
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))`

**and this in the urls.py:**
`from . import views
from django.urls import path

`urlpatterns = [ path('', views.index, name='home'), path('', views.BookingList.as_view(), name='bookings'), ]`
`

The ValueError then appeared.

Comment: as per your Error, it means you're not signed out yet. can you check `print(request.user.is_authenticated)` this return `True` or `False`?

Comment: have you tried the setting `LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL`? Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#logout-redirect-url

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)